# Dropdown menu pushes content away

Tags: html, css

http://borbelykertlabor.hu/

On the top menu click on "BLOG" then you will find a menu on the right side under that circle logo if you click on "Dísznövények" the menu will drop down, if there is a too long string content between `<li>` elements it pushes the whole ul menu to left.

Comment: The site mentioned in this question appears now to be unreachable, which means this question no longer has an [mcve], and it needs to be put on hold. Please always make questions as self-contained as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `kategoriak` element is absolute positioned.  But it has not been given a width.  The fact that it originally aligns and looks good in the corner is just coincidence!

So when the content changes, it just grows the width to fit the content.  If you restrain this element with a width (e.g. `width: 225px`) , then the menu will not change the width and instead the content will wrap.